# Google DataFlow SDK compilation error

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have pulled DataFlow SDK and successfully managed to open it as an eclipse project. 
In total I see 66 errors and the basic issue is

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The constructor SpecificDatumReader(Class) refers to the missing type User  AvroIOTest.java /google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io  line 125    Java Problem

I dont know where this class is located.

Answer (score 2):

The compile errors you are getting are caused by an improper settings in your Eclipse environment and its binding to the Maven lifecycle.

Specifically, in our test build, Dataflow SDK uses `avro-maven-plugin` to generate Java sources from an Avro schema file. That plugin automatically generates Java classes that are needed for the test build to succeed. The plugin runs during Maven's `generate-test-sources` phase, which Eclipse probably doesn't run by default. This experience is something that we are actively looking to improve.

That said, if you are looking to use Dataflow SDK, this shouldn't impact you **at all**. You can create a new `Maven Project` in Eclipse, depend on our artifact from Maven Central, and start working on your Dataflow pipeline. As a remainder, our artifact lives within group id `com.google.cloud.dataflow` under the artifact id of `google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all`.

Alternatively, if you are actually looking to contribute to the Dataflow SDK itself, as apposed to using it and building pipelines with it, we'd suggest, in the immediate term, to either use Maven directly or try mangling with your Eclipse and `m2e` plugin settings. Rest assured, however, that we'll be improving Eclipse experience sometime soon.

**UPDATE:**

We have improved user experience for both scenarios.

If you are looking to use the SDK, we now have a starter project for Eclipse [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/tree/master/eclipse/starter). Just import this starter project into Eclipse by selecting `Existing Projects into Workspace` option in the `Import` dialog.

If you are looking to contribute to the SDK, try selecting `Existing Maven Projects` option in the `Import` dialog and point it to the entire repository.